# can't convert from char * to const char *&

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have a funciton like

```
    void foo(const char *&str)
    {
         cout<<str<<endl;
    }
```

used like:

```
    void main()
    {
        foo("hello");
        char *h = "hello"
        foo(h);
    }
```

but both got an **error**

```
"can't convert from const char[] to const char *&"
```

if I change `foo` to `void foo(const char *)`, there is no error can't I use `const char *&` as parameter

Comment: I think you would want to use const char *str in the function definition.

Comment: @simpleBob i think he should make it `reference to a constant char pointer`(const char* const & str) since he is passing rvalue in the first call. should work for second call too

Comment: @Koushik In general, you're right.  But in the case of `char const*`, there's really no point---you might as well just pass by value.  (Of course, things like `char const* const&` as argument type do occur when instantiating templates; e.g. this will be the argument type of `std::vector<char const*>::push_back`.)

Answer (score 2):

You got an error because the conversion is illegal.  The reason
it is illegal is simple: it breaks `const` without requiring
a `const_cast`.

As an example of why it is forbidden, imagine that `foo` was:

```
void
foo( char const*& str )
{
    str = "abc";
}

int
main()
{
    char* h;
    foo( h );
    *h = '1';
}
```

If you're not going to modify `str` in `foo`, pass by value. 
Pass by reference will works *if* you have `char const* const&`,
but there's no reason to use it here.  It works because the
additional const means that you can bind a temporary to it (as
in the case of `foo( "hello" )`, where the argument is
a temporary resulting from the conversion of `char const[6]` to
`char const*`, and `foo( h )` works, because the implicit const
conversions will work (in C++, but not in C!), as long as you
add const everywhere (and not just at one level).

Also, your code also uses a deprecated conversion to initialize
`h`.  You should get a warning here.  And `void main` is an
error, and shouldn't compile.

### Edit:

Just to be clear, there's no problem with:

```
void f( char const*& str );
```

But you can only call it with an lvalue of type `char const*`;
anything else will either result in an illegal implicit const
conversion, or try to initialize a non-const reference with an
rvalue, which is illegal.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what `char const* const&` does? Why do you need the "const" twice?

Comment: @akristmann There are two things which can be immutable: the pointer itself, and the data it points to.  `const` applies to whatever is to the left of it, so in `char const* const&`, the first const means that the pointed to `char` are constant, and the second that the pointer is constant.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
int main()
{
    const char *h = "hello";
    foo(h);
}
```

Comment: "hello" is actually const char *const, so it can't conert to const *

Comment: @user2269250 Firstly conversion from `const char* const` to `const char*` is legal. Secondly "hello" is actually `char[]`.